# best_in_place using :display_as - how do I update the value of the <input> as well as the <span>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I've got a `best_in_place` form where I am doing some post-processing of the data that gets submitted. It's a series of times, and I'm formatting them into a consistent format before saving. How do I get the updated value to be shown on the form after saving?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could only find a slightly hacky way of doing this. First, set the `display_as` parameter on the form helper to be the same as the actual attribute being displayed.

```
= best_in_place @post, :name, type: :input, :display_as => :name
```

Then, add a javascript handler for `best_in_place:success`

```
$(document).on('best_in_place:success', function(e, data) {
  $(this).data('bestInPlaceEditor').original_content = data['display_as'];
});
```

When the post is saved and the `name` attribute is updated, the new value will be returned as JSON: it will look like `{"display_as": "updated post name"}`. This javascript gets the value that is returned and sets it to the BIP editor's `original_content` attribute. When BIP renders the input (when you click on the post's name to edit it), the value of `original_content` is displayed.

Tested using best_in_place 2.1.0. The relevant code in best_in_place.js is:

```
if (response !== null && response.hasOwnProperty("display_as")) {
  this.element.attr("data-original-content", this.element.text());
  this.original_content = this.element.text();
  this.element.html(response["display_as"]);
}
```

Here `this.element` is the  that display when the field is not being edited. So, it's getting set with a different value to what `original_content` (which is what the  gets when rendered) is. I'm not sure if this is intended or a bug in best_in_place.

Comment: `best_in_place:success` event is never fired

Comment: What version are you using @YossiS ?

Comment: mmm just realized i'm using 1.1.2. So i guess they must have changed the events.

Comment: Yeah I suspect so, this is for version 2.1